# Root directory of web server

Tags: apache, webserver

What is the root directory of Apache Web Server?

I am using Windows XP. My Apache server is installed at:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\
```

I want to host a server and its manual says:

> *move all files and subdirectories from that directory to the root directory of the web server*

Comment: There is no www folder in C: drive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you've configured the server. The 'root directory' is actually called the **document root**, which is the directory from which the Apache HTTP server would serve files from. It can be changed using the [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive, which you should be able to find inside the configuration file(s) (e.g. `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`).

From the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/urlmapping.html#documentroot):

> For example, if `DocumentRoot` were set to `/var/www/html` then a request for `http://www.example.com/fish/guppies.html` would result in the file `/var/www/html/fish/guppies.html` being served to the requesting client.